# Low water pressure at toilets after main supply valve replacement

Tags: water

Just replaced my main water valve that feeds the house. It's copper line and I used shark bite fittings. Kitchen sink, master shower and both toilets have very low pressure now. All other faucets are fine. Tried clearing the braided lines in kitchen sink. Got some sediment out but still nothing. What else can I do?

Comment: Debris/sediment. Flush everything and exercise all valves. Be prepared to shut off water supply to address additional leaks at old valves and fixtures.

Answer (score 1):

Some toilet valves can be taken apart to flush the sediment out. Turn off the valve that supplies the toilet and flush it. This will allow the fill valve to depressurize. I have been able to clean two types. Both had some arrows / instructions, one you pushed down and rotated the top of the fill valve and it pulled straight up then slight turn the water on--this clears the stuff in the line (I found putting a glass on top allowed me to turn the water up and really clear the line).

The second type I have only had ~75% luck with they have 2 plastic clips that you slip a small screwdriver under and lift the cap same as above for flushing, but use caution the plastic breaks very easily and a valve replacement is needed. As for the other valve / tub, if it has a shower head or arrestor they need to be cleaned also. If it has washerless valves you may need to disassemble the valve flush and reassemble.

Answer (score -2):

I'd blame the SharkBite, since that's all that changed. They reduce the pipe diameter dramatically. This doesn't affect pressure but could very well be affecting volume or replenishment of evacuating water. This would appear to be a drop in pressure for longer runs & higher outlets. Replace the SharkBite Ball Valve with a Compression Fit Ball Valve to see if that remedies the situation, it should.

Comment: The Sharkbite may be all that *intentionally* changed, but taking apart and reassembling plumbing causes all kinds of troubles by sediment and debris even when *nothing has been changed*.

Comment: Yep, you, J. Stan, Jimmy & Ed are quite correct on the simple debris stuff, but only the first singular fixture used would get the drop problem. However, no-one addressed how "everything at once" would suddenly have a drop. Only If, the Main & its supply-line were 3/4" & everything afterward was 1/2" would the Asker have no difference with the SharkBites. Just my experience & what I saw no-one else addressed from lack of knowledge. SharkBites are horrible creatures if they aren't used at just the fixture ends where the volume will be rightly reduced by the fixture or its supply lines anyhow.